# SQL Statement to delete only one row out of duplicates

Tags: ruby, postgresql, duplicates

So I am working in Ruby, and say I have 6 rows in a table of two columns that are exactly identical. In my case, my table "campaign_items" has two columns "campaign_name" and "item." I would like to delete only one row out of the 6 duplicates using a single query. I started with this:

```
db.exec("DELETE FROM products WHERE campaign_name = '#{camp_name}' AND product_type = 'fleecejacket' AND size = '#{size_array[index]}'")
```

Which of course deleted all items of that condition. So I found in another question an answer along these lines:

```
db.exec("DELETE FROM products a WHERE a.ctid <> (SELECT min(b.ctid) FROM products b WHERE a.key = b.key)")
```

However, this would delete all duplicates except for one. I have not found a way that only deletes a SINGLE row that has duplicates. Is there a delete top query that I am looking for? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I also have a column "id" which is a primary key.

Comment: You should be extremely cautious when injecting arbitrary user data into your queries, it can create [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). If there's a way to do this with your ORMs `where` scope, which should be possible, do it that way first.

Comment: @tadman Yes I know. However the user input is done by a site administrator who knows the correct format to insert the data and is the only person able to access it. Also, we have backups done regularly of the database in case this 1 in 1 million thing happens.

Comment: This is still extremely dangerous. At the absolute least you should escape those values, or better still, use placeholder values if your database driver supports it. This takes very little effort to do and avoids the risk of accidental disasters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I definitely overthought this, but all that is needed is this:

```
x = db.exec("SELECT * FROM campaign_items WHERE campaign_name = '#{camp_name}' AND item = 'fleecejacket'")

id = x[0]['id']

db.exec("DELETE FROM campaign_items WHERE campaign_name = '#{camp_name}' AND item = 'fleecejacket' AND id = '#{id}'")
```

Get the unique id from the first duplicate (since it doesn't matter which one is deleted) and delete the row with that id.